# Confused about proving that a group of functions is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, function-and-relation-composition

I'm studying for my Group Theory test, and one thing I keep getting stuck on is in the sections of "groups of permutations".

For example, take $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\neq0,1\}$ and $G=\{\varepsilon, f, g\}$, where $\varepsilon(x)=x$ (i.e. the identity function) $\,f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$, and $\,g(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$.

This says that $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $G$ is a set of permutations on $A$. The first is obvious (I guess you could write it as $A=\mathbb{R}-\{0,1\}$), but I'm used to seeing permutations written in the matrix-type notation, on finite sets, i.e.

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\2&3&1&5&4\end{pmatrix}=(123)(45)$$

Given these explicit functions, which I can guess are indeed permutations of $A$ since the definition of a function $f:A\to A$ is that it maps elements of $A$ to (perhaps) other elements of $A$, how should I show that

1. G is closed under (what I suppose to be) the operation of function composition
2. G is closed under inversion

thus proving that G is a subgroup of $S_A$?

What's confusing me is the fact that each element in $G$ is not given by one explicit function, like $G=\{f\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)=x^2, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ for example, where I could plug arbitrary numbers $x_1, x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ into the function to show that any real numbers under this function are indeed also real numbers.

Do I take each function separately, and prove that $f\circ f$, $f\circ g$, $g\circ g$, etc are all closed under the operation and inversion? Or is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're OK being pragmatic, you could note that since $G$ only consists of three functions, then **if** it's a group, it had better be isomorphic to the cyclic group with three elements.

So, you could try and show that $G$ is generated by, say, $f$. That is, show that $f^2 = f \circ f = g$, while $f^3 = f \circ f \circ f = \varepsilon$ so that $G = \{f^k : k = 0, 1, 2\} \cong C_3$. I haven't exactly verified this, but if $G$ is a group in which $\varepsilon$ is the identity, then this must be so. You could frame this as using the [finite subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Subgroup_Test) and additionally exhibiting an isomorphism between your group and the cyclic group with three elements.

Just keep in mind that a permutation of $A$ is simply a bijection (that is, invertible function) $A \to A$. As you point out, there are too many real numbers to use the matrix/cycle notation, but you have definitely encountered permutations before seeing those notations (for example, any function $L(x) = mx + b$ with $m \neq 0$ is a permutation of $\Bbb R$).

Answer (score 0):

Compute $(g(f(x))$ by substituting $f(x) = \frac 1 {1 - x}$ for $y$ in $g(y) = \frac {y - 1} y$ and simplify to obtain x:
$$
\begin{align}
g\left(\frac 1 {1-x}\right) &= \frac {{\frac 1 {1-x}} - 1} {\frac 1 {1-x}} \\
\\
&= \frac {\frac {1-(1-x)} {1-x}} {\frac 1 {1-x}} \\
&= x
\end{align}
$$

This shows that $g \circ f = \varepsilon$, the identity function, which is the two-sided identity element for function composition. Because composition is the group operation, $\varepsilon$ is the group identity element/unit/whatever term you're familiar with.

If you now show that $f(g(x)) = x$ for any/all $x$, you will have proved similarly that $f \circ g = \varepsilon$. From these two facts, it follows that $f = g^{-1}$ and $g = f^{-1}$.

You also need to show that the group is closed under composition. Given the above, it suffices to show that $f \circ f$ and $g \circ g$ are in the group. It's enough to show that $f \circ f = g$, because then $g \circ g = f^{-1} \circ f^{-1} = (f \circ f)^{-1} = g^{-1} = f$. To show $f \circ f = g$, simplify $f(f(x))$, which is:
$$
\frac 1 {1 - \frac 1 {1-x}} 
$$
to show that it equals $\frac {x-1} x$.

Comment: Do I not need to show the same for $\varepsilon$? Also what about inverses?

Comment: You will have shown that inverses exist. The only other thing to show is that $f \circ f$ and $g \circ g$ are in the set, because $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ both equal the identity. See the last paragraph I added: you only have to show that $f \circ f = g$.

Comment: Clearly (yes?) $\varepsilon \circ h = h \circ \varepsilon = h$ for any function $h$, thus in particular for these three.